# Communication between classes/Listeners

Tags: java, javafx, onclicklistener

I want to create an application with a button and a colour picker on the top and a canvas in the centre of a `BorderPane`. I created a main Class `TestSceneBuilder` and 2 listeners: one for the button and one for the ColorPicker. The question is: when I detect change in colour how do I pass it to my CerchioListener ?

**Main Class:**

```
public class TestSceneBuilder extends Application {
    final int H = 300, W = 300; //height and width
    BorderPane root;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = this.setScene();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, H, W);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    /**
     * This method is supposed to build the scene with all components:
     * a button "Draw" that draws the rectangle
     * a canvas
     * a colorPicker
     * @return 
     */
    BorderPane setScene(){
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        final ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker(Color.AQUA);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(H, W);
        Button btn = new Button("Draw");
        /*CerchioListner should get the mouse clicked event and draw the circle*/
        final CerchioListner l = new CerchioListner(canvas, cp.getValue());
        btn.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, l);

        /*ColorListener intercept the color change in ColorPicker cp and change the color of the
        shape drawn*/
        ColorListener cl = new ColorListener(cp);
        cp.setOnAction(cl);

        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(btn, cp);
        border.setTop(hb);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(hb, Pos.CENTER);

        border.setCenter(canvas);
        return border;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Button listener: CerchioListener**

```
public class CerchioListner implements javafx.event.EventHandler{
Canvas canvas = null;
Color colore;
public CerchioListner(Canvas c, Color colore) {
    this.canvas = c;
    this.colore = colore;
}

public void changeColor(Color c) {
    this.colore = c;
}
@Override
public void handle(Event t) {
    disegna();
}
public void disegna(){
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(colore);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
    }  
}
```

**Color Picker listener: ColorListener**

```
public class ColorListener implements javafx.event.EventHandler{
ColorPicker cp = null;
public ColorListener(ColorPicker cp) {
    this.cp = cp;
}

@Override
public void handle(Event t) {
    Color c = cp.getValue();
    System.out.println("handle CP "+cp.getValue());

    //restituisciColoreSelezionato(c);
}

/*public Color restituisciColoreSelezionato(Color c){
    return c;
}*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that is not the best you can have:

- You have a `Canvas`, which is not member of `Main`, just a local variable in `setScene()`, therefore it is only accessible in that method. As the `Canvas` is the most important part of your class, you should have it as a class member because you want to access it anywhere from the class.
- The listener for the `Button` should not store any reference to the selected color and to the `Canvas`, it is stored by `Main` and the listener should use that member.
- The listener of the `ColorPicker` should not store any reference to the `ColorPicker` itself. The `ColorPicker` should be a member to make it able to access the currently selected color anywhere in `Main`.

*I have updated your code to include these modifications:*

```
public class TestSceneBuilder extends Application {
    final int H = 300, W = 300;
    BorderPane root;
    Canvas canvas;
    ColorPicker cp;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = this.setScene();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, H, W);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    BorderPane setScene(){
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();

        cp = new ColorPicker(Color.AQUA);
        canvas = new Canvas(H, W);
        btn = new Button("Draw");

        btn.setOnAction((event) -> {
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(cp.getValue());
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
        });


        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(btn, cp);
        border.setTop(hb);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(hb, Pos.CENTER);

        border.setCenter(canvas);
        return border;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**If you want to stay with external listeners:**

Exchange this:

```
btn.setOnAction((event) -> {
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(cp.getValue());
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
});
```

with

```
CerchioListener cerchioListener = new CerchioListener(canvas);
btn.setOnAction(cerchioListener);
cerchioListener.colorProperty.bind(cp.valueProperty());
```

and add the listener:

*CerchioListener.java*

```
public class CerchioListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private Canvas canvas = null;
    public ObjectProperty<Color> colorProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Color>(Color.WHITE);

    public CerchioListener(Canvas c) {
        this.canvas = c;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(colorProperty.get());
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me check if I understood it 1) every time I want to use an object (in this case i want to paint on `Canvas` in different Listeners) I should declare it as Object of the main class? (in my case the main class is `TestSceneBuilder`). 2) The Listener for the button should have its own `Color color` variable and not `Canvas` because it's allready stored in `TestSceneBuilder` and I can access it from the whole Package, right? 2) My `ColorPicker` does not need any `ColorPicker` object inside becouse I can access the one in `TestSceneBuilder`. Right?

Comment: 1) Correct. 2) Not correct (I mistyped): the listener shall not store anything, just use the members of `TestSceneBuilder` - as in the example it uses cp and canvas which are the member of `TestSceneBuilder`. 3) The !listener! for the value change of the `ColorPicker` shall not store any reference. As you can see in the example I don't even have a listener for the `ColorPicker`.

Comment: I may be boring but let's say i have to use an external listener and I want the listener  to be able to access the `canvas`, I'll have to declare `canvas`  as `final` in my main class, rigt? Otherwise I get the error messagge "not static variable can be accessd from static enviroment" when I try to access it using `TestClassCommunication.canvas` in `handle` method of my listener

Comment: If you implement the listener outside of `TestSceneBuilder`, you will have no reference for the members of `TestSceneBuilder` - in this case you have to pass the refereces to the listener objects - that is you tried. To avoid this you can implement these classes inside `TestSceneBuilder`, they become inner classes and they have reference to the members of `TestSceneBuilder`. One step forward, to not give a name to the listener: `btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {...});`, thats called anonymous inner class, which is an inner class w/o name. And one more step is lambda expression.

Comment: I got it. The point was that I'll be asked to implement external listeners in my exam so, I'm better learn how to do it :). So are you saying In this case I should keep a `Canvas canvas;` as member of my Listener and when I create the  listener i create it like: `CircleDrawerListener cdl = new CircleDrawerListener(canvas)` and inside the constructor of the listener I'll put `this.canvas = canvas;`, right? By the way I tryed to add `static` in fornt of  `canvas` and `ColorPicker cp` in my main class and I was able to access it from an external listener. Are both methods valid? how do I chose?

Comment: I have updated the code for you to show how to implement it by using an external listener.